# Issue with reading HTML-based XLS with C#

Tags: c#, csv, visual-studio-2012, xls

I'm trying to read an HTML-based .xls file provided by a vendor and convert it to a csv for a different process to import. I've found tons of solutions that can read and convert, the most popular using OLEDB to read it in. I had this working last week in VS2010 but then installed VS2012/.NET4.5 and suddenly it doesn't recognize the source file and nothing I do can get it functional again - I've even tried installing VS2010 on a different machine and it won't behave (so I'm not sure how it worked on the original machine). If I run the code as is, the cnn.Open() throws an exception stating "External table is not in the expected format." If I change the connection string to the line that is commented out it reads the file but not properly (not everything is read and the data is not populated correctly).

So, in summary, what is the best way (preferably without a 3rd party library/app) to read the file at the bottom of this post using C#?

Here's the code

```cs
string excelFilePath = @"C:\Users\Dan\test.xls";
string csvOutputFile = @"C:\Users\Dan\output.csv";
int worksheetNumber = 1;
// connection string
var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", excelFilePath);
//var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"HTML Import;IMEX=1;HDR=NO\"", excelFilePath);

var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);
// get schema, then data
var dt = new DataTable();
try
{
    cnn.Open();
    var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    if (schemaTable.Rows.Count < worksheetNumber) throw new ArgumentException("The worksheet number provided cannot be found in the spreadsheet");
    string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[worksheetNumber - 1]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
    string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheet);
    var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
    da.Fill(dt);
 }
 catch (Exception e){}
 finally{cnn.Close();}

 // write out CSV data
 using (var wtr = new StreamWriter(csvOutputFile))
 {
     foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
     {
         bool firstLine = true;
         foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
         {
             if (!firstLine) { wtr.Write(","); } else { firstLine = false; }
                 var data = row[col.ColumnName].ToString().Replace("\"", "\"\"");
                 wtr.Write(String.Format("\"{0}\"", data));
             }
             wtr.WriteLine();
          }
     }
```

Here's the file that I'm reading from, sent to us with a .xls extension.

```xml
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta name="ProgId" content="Excel.Sheet"/>
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Excel 10"/>
<!--[if !mso]>
<style>
v\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}");
o\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}");
x\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}");
.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}");
</style>");
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<x:ExcelWorkbook>
<x:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:ExcelWorksheet>
<x:Name>report</w:Name>
<x:WorksheetOptions>
<x:ProtectContents>False</w:ProtectContents>
<x:ProtectObjects>False</w:ProtectObjects>
<x:ProtectScenarios>False</w:ProtectScenarios>
</w:WorksheetOptions>
</w:ExcelWorksheet>
</w:ExcelWorksheets>
<x:ProtectStructure>False</w:ProtectStructure>
<x:ProtectWindows>False</w:ProtectWindows>
</w:ExcelWorkbook>");
</xml><![endif]-->
<head>

<style>
br {mso-data-placement:same-cell;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<style>
table {
mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";
}
</style>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td align=center colspan=6 valign=top>
<span class="pageHead">
<nobr><h1>Status</h1></nobr></span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align=center colspan=6 valign=top>
<span class="pageHead"><nobr>
Generated by User
</nobr></span>
</td></tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>Owner</th>
<th>Project Id</th>
<th>Event Id</th>
<th>Event Title</th>
<th>Event Status</th>
<th>EventSummary</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>test1</td>
<td>event1</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>test2</td>
<td>event2</td>
<td>Pending Selection</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>test3</td>
<td>event3</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>test4</td>
<td>event4</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>test5</td>
<td>event5</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>6</td>
<td>test6</td>
<td>event6</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>test7</td>
<td>event7</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>test8</td>
<td>event8</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>test9</td>
<td>event9</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>test10</td>
<td>event10</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>test11</td>
<td>event11</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>test12</td>
<td>event12</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>test13</td>
<td>event13</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>test14</td>
<td>event14</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>test15</td>
<td>event15</td>
<td>Completed</td>
<td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! So, after looking at the original data and some other examples, I realized that there are two separate tables within the sheet and that the OLEDB driver was interpreting that as two separate sheets. I changed the worksheet variable to 2 and that retrieved the second "table" of data which is what I was really interested in. So, by cycling through all the "worksheets" I should be able to get all of the data out of this sheet.